# How to cancel the stripe payment and debit the money to client account

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Hello I am using following code for transaction

```
require_once('Stripe/lib/Stripe.php');
    Stripe::setApiKey("<Api key>");

    $customer  = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => 1500,
  "currency" => "usd",
  "card" => $_POST['stripeToken'],
  "description" => "Charge for Facebook Login code."
));
echo "<pre>";print_r($customer);die;

// Charge the Customer instead of the card
$charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => 1500,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "customer" => $customer->id)
);
echo 'Transaction Id '.$charge->id;
```

I have one cancel button if i click on that the payment which done by user will be revert back to client account

Answer (score 1):

You'll most likely need to refund the money you charged from the card and then have the Cancel button run the charge on the customer instead.

This can be accomplished as followed:

(1) Retrieve the charge's identifier:

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    ...
));

// you can use the var_dump function to see what's inside the $charge object
// var_dump($charge);

$chargeID = $charge->id;
```

(2) Refund the user:

```
$re = \Stripe\Refund::create(array(
  "charge" => $chargeID
));
```

(3) Charge the customer instead:

```
// Charge the Customer instead of the card
$charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => 1500,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "customer" => $customer->id)
);
echo 'Transaction Id '.$charge->id;
```